# Calculate the matrix M such M.X=omega

Tags: matrix

I would like to determine the matrix M[3,3] such as M.X=w.

```
ω = {Cos[ψ[t]] Derivative[1][θ][t] + 
   Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ψ[t]] Derivative[1][φ][t], 
  Sin[ψ[t]] Derivative[1][θ][t] - 
   Cos[ψ[t]] Sin[θ[t]] Derivative[1][φ][t], 
  Cos[θ[t]] Derivative[1][φ][t] + 
   Derivative[1][ψ][t]}

X = {Derivative[1][φ][t], Derivative[1][θ][t], 
  Derivative[1][ψ][t]}
```

**Can anyone help me to find a short code to this purpose ?**

I add some steps thanks to your comments :

```
In[26]:= ω = (Ω (3 | 0)^B3)

Out[26]= {Cos[ψ[t]] θ'[t] + Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ψ[t]] ϕ'[t], Sin[ψ[t]] θ'[t] - 
  Cos[ψ[t]] Sin[θ[t]] ϕ'[t], Cos[θ[t]] ϕ'[t] + ψ'[t]}

In[27]:= ϵ = {ϕ'[t], θ'[t], ψ'[t]}

In[28]:= Thread[Array[M, {3, 3}].ϵ == ω]

Out[28]= {M[1, 2] θ'[t] + M[1, 1] ϕ'[t] + M[1, 3] ϕ'[t] == Cos[ψ[t]] θ'[t] + 
   Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ψ[t]] ϕ'[t][t], M[2, 2] θ'[t] + M[2, 1] ϕ'[t] + M[2, 3] ψ'[t] == 
  Sin[ψ[t]] θ'[t] - Cos[ψ[t]] Sin[θ[t]] ϕ'[t][t], 
 M[3, 2] θ'[t] + M[3, 1] ϕ'[t] + M[3, 3] ψ'[t] == Cos[θ[t]] ϕ'[t] + ψ'[t]}


SolveAlways[%, ϵ]

{{M[1, 2] -> Cos[ψ[t]], M[1, 3] -> 0, M[2, 3] -> 0, 
  Cos[θ[t]] -> M[3, 1], M[3, 2] -> 0, M[3, 3] -> 1, 
  M[2, 1] -> -Cos[ψ[t]] Sin[θ[t]], 
  M[2, 2] -> Sin[ψ[t]], 
  M[1, 1] -> Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ψ[t]]}}
```

It only remains a slight step.
**How can I assign these different values so as to obtain the M matrix with these values?**

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have a look at `LinearSolve`.

Comment: The solution is not unique.  The trivial solution is `DiagonalMatrix[\[Omega]/X]`.  Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Here the result I would to obtain with a Mathematica code

M = {{Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ψ[t]] , -Cos[ψ[t]], 
   0}, {-Cos[ψ[t]] Sin[θ[t]] , Sin[ψ[t]] , 
   1}, {Cos[θ[t]], 0, 1}}

Indeed, the solution by hand is trivial but the matrix is not diagonal

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you want to do?

`Array[M, {3, 3}].X == \[Omega] // Thread // SolveAlways[#, {\[Theta]'[t], \[Phi]'[t], \[Psi]'[t]}] &`

Comment: It helps me a lot. I have almost the result I'm looking for. Thank you.